# AS3: how to pass by "object"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I was actually looking for a way to pass by reference in AS3 but then it seemed that adobe and lots of people's understanding of pass by reference is different from what I have been taught at the university. I was taught java was pass by value and C++ allowed pass by reference.

I'm not trying to argue what pass by value and reference are. I just want to explain why I'm using pass by object in the question...

Back to the question, I would like to do something like:

```
public function swapCard(cardA:Cards, cardB:Cards) {
    var temp:Cards = cardA;
    cardA = cardB;
    cardB = temp;
}

...

swapCard(c1, c2);
```

EDIT: adding two examples on how I'm using the swapCard function

1) in the process of swaping a card between player1 and player2's hand

```
swapCard(player1.hand[s], player2.hand[t]);
```

2) in the process of swaping a card between player1's hand and deck

```
swapCard(player1.hand[s], player1.deck[rand]);
```

In C++, we only need to add a symbol before the parameters to make it work (and we call THIS pass by reference). But in AS3, cardA and cardB are just pointers to the formal parameters. Here in the function, changing the pointers does not do anything to the formal parameters :(

I have been searching for hours but I couldn't find a way to without knowing all the properties of the Cards.

If I have to change the properties of the cards one by one then maybe I should change swapCard to a static function in class Cards? (because I don't want to expose everything to another class) I'm not sure if this is a good practice either. This is like adding a swap_cars function into class Cars. If I let this happen, what will be next? Wash car, lend car, rent car... I really want to keep the Cards class clean and holds only the details of the card. Is there a possible way to do this properly in AS3?

Comment: In AS3 you can _only_ pass objects by reference. Only primitive types can be passed by value (those cannot be passed by reference unless you put them inside more complex objects and pass those).

Comment: Objects are passed by reference and primitives are passed by value in AS3. This is same in Java, contrary to the statement in your question

Comment: Where and how are these cards used, and what is your intent on swapping them?

Comment: about pass by reference and value I think it really depends on how you define pass by reference. http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Comment: The cards are used in a battle/card game and the swap function is used before and during the battle. I'm trying to make classes reusable for my future games and thus all these troubles :(

Comment: If you post some code (perhaps on a new question) there is surely a design that is re-usable and clean without the need to swap references (which is impossible in AS3 as you've already learned).

Comment: @FailFlash It's unlikely that you need to swap references to finish your game. I've written several games (an other applications) in AS3 and I never needed the ability to perform a C-like swap. Please post a new question with code details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. I think I can get this done without using this kind of swap. However, a swapCard(player1Hand[s], player2Hand[t]) or swapCard(player1Hand[s], player1Deck[rand]) seems easy to use and I can follow the logic better this way >_<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The kind of `swap` function that you're trying to implement is not possible in AS3. The input parameters are references to the input objects but the references themselves are passed by value. This means that inside the function you can change the `cardA` and `cardB` but those changes will not be visible outside the function.

**Edit**: I added this portion after you edited your question with sample usage.

It seems like you're trying to swap two objects in 2 different arrays at given array positions in each - you can create a function for this in AS3 but not the way you attempted.

One possible implementation is to pass the arrays themselves and the positions that you're trying to exchange; something like this:

```
// Assumes arrays and indices are correct.
public function SwapCards(playerHand:Array, playerCardIndex:int,
    playerDeck:Array, playerDeckIndex:int):void
{
    var tempCard:Card = playerHand[playerHandIndex];

    playerHand[playerHandIndex] = playerDeck[playerDeckIndex];
    playerDeck[playerDeckIndex] = tempCard;
}
```

Note that you still exchange references and the arrays themselves are still passed by reference (and the array references are passed by value - you could, if you wanted, change the arrays to new arrays inside this function but you wouldn't see new arrays outside). However, because the array parameters refer to the same arrays inside and outside the function, you *can* make changes to the *contents* of the array (or other array properties) and those changes *will* be visible outside.

This solution is faster than cloning the card because that involves allocating memory for a new `Card` instance (which is expensive) and that temporary instance will also have to be freed by the garbage collector (which is also expensive).

You mentioned in a comment that you pass cards down to lower levels of code - if you don't have a back reference to the arrays (and the positions of the cards), you will not be able to easily swap cards - in AS3, all input parameters are copies (either the copy of the value for primitive types or the copy of the reference for complex objects - changes to the input parameters in a function will not be visible outside).

Comment: yea just as aaron say, direct references to the cards will not be changed by the swap functions... I guess in the end I have to keep back references like you've said. And keep an array to store all cards so I can pass the cards array and index through functions...........

Comment: @FailFlash Try to first come up with a good data structure for your game - having good context that's available everywhere in the game source will make it much easier to implement the game.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: renaming the function from clone to copyFrom as pointed out by aaron. Seems like clone is supposed to be used as objA = objB.clone()

At this point, I'm adding a copyFrom() function in the Cards class such that

```
var temp:Cards = new Cards(...);
var a:Cards = new Cards(...);
...
temp.copyFrom(a);
...
```

temp will be copying everything from a.

```
public function swapCard(cardA:Cards, cardB:Cards) {
    var temp:Cards = new Cards();
    temp.copyFrom(cardA);
    cardA.copyFrom(cardB);
    cardB.copyFrom(temp);
}
```

I will wait for a week or so to see if there are any other options

Comment: You should really post a new question with details about what you're trying to achieve. So far all we've seen is that you're trying to create a swap function but we don't know what it is that you're actually trying to do. Your implementation works but is not particularly efficient (not too bad, either). If you post actual details (rather than going on about how C++ does this) we may be able to recommend  better alternative. AS3 is not C++ and there are things that must be done differently.

Comment: Right, we don't know what "other options" there might be because we don't know how your code is setup to begin with. Your clone function (which I would call a `copyFrom()`) is fine, but I'd bet there is a "better" way to swap your cards. Are they stored in an array? Swap their positions in the array. Are they properties of some state object? Swap their references on the state object. Etc.

Comment: There are two reasons why I'm not posting more code here. First, most of my code are still in algorithm form written on dozens pieces of paper x___x .  And 2nd, I think that no matter what we do, in the end we still need a swap action between two cards. Whether we are swapping the cards between arrays or swapping them on the state object, since I am passing cards as parameters down layers of functions, I will still face this pass by ref/value problem. P.S. Added two example on how I am using swapCard in the question, hope it helps...

Comment: @FailFlash I updated my answer following your edits.

Answer (score 0):

You have some good answers already, but based on the comments back-and-forth with me, here's my suggestion (I use "left" and "right" naming because it helps me visualize, but it doesn't matter):

```
function swapCard(leftCards:Array, leftCard:Card, rightCards:Array, rightCard:Card):void {
    var leftIndex:int = leftCards.indexOf(leftCard);
    var rightIndex:int = rightCards.indexOf(rightCard);
    leftCards[leftIndex] = rightCard;
    rightCards[rightIndex] = leftCard;
}
```

Now you can swap the cards in the two examples you posted like this:

```
swapCard(player1.hand, player1.hand[s], player2.hand, player2.hand[t]);

swapCard(player1.hand, player1.hand[s], player1.deck, player1.deck[rand]);
```

However, note that while this swaps the cards in the arrays, it does not swap direct references to the cards in those arrays. In other words:

```
var a:Card = player1.hand[0];
var b:Card = player2.hand[0];
swapCard(player1.hand, a, player2.hand, b);
// does not change the references a and b, they still refer to the same card
a == player2.hand[0];
a != player1.hand[0];
b == player1.hand[0];
b != player2.hand[0];
```

Typically, this sort of thing is handled by dispatching a "changed" event so that any code that cares about the state of a player's hand array will know to re-evaluate the state of the hand.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Dispatching event at a change of references is new to me, will definitely look into it. Thank you again for the help

Comment: @FailFlash You should re-evaluate what you pass around in your game. Passing a single card seems to be insufficient - even in this answer, you still need access to the array that currently holds the card. You need more context (likely in most levels of your game source) - once you have that established, this whole swap problem becomes trivial.

Comment: yea C++'s pass by reference is completely different from as3 and since I wrote everything with C++'s pass by reference in mind, I basically need to change all the functions now and the reasons for me to use the original swap function are gone :< Might as well just close this question.

Comment: Or accept @xxbbcc's answer, he pretty much summed it up by saying "it's not possible in AS3". ;)

Comment: oh.. i thought upvote means accept and then it says I need 15 rep so.. I'm too noob for this x)  thank you again for you two's help.

Answer (score -1):

There's a deep misunderstanding going on here. The question is about object reference but the PO is not trying to swap any Object reference at all.

The problem comes from the fact that the PO does not understand the difference between variable and objects. He's trying to swap variable/object reference which is not dynamically possible of course. He wants with a function to make the variable holding a reference to Object A, swap its object reference with another variable. Since Objects can be passed around but not variables (since they are just holders (not pointers)) the task is not possible without a direct use of the given variable.

To resume:

variables are not Objects!
variables hold a reference to an object.
variables cannot be passed in function or referenced in functions because THEY ARE NOT OBJECTS.

Comment: thats why i said pointers are passed to the function as the parameters.. basically pointers are similar to the references you are talking about

Comment: You can vote me down all you want but isn't that true that you want a function to swap not 2 object but the variable? As in var a reference object A and var b reference object B and after calling a function var a reference object B and var b reference object A. Really if this is not what you are going for then say it and I delete the answer. If it is remove your vote down and accept the answer.

Comment: just to say its not me who vote you down... i dont have enough reputation for my votes to be in effect.